# Не получается вывод с помощью PRINT_NUM

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Привет есть такой код:

```
include emu8086.inc
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
begin:
mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset sprtMessage
mov ax, 1111b
mov bx, 1101b 
and ax, bx         
call print_num 
int 21h
or ax, bx;         
call print_num 
int 21h
xor ax, bx;         
call print_num 
int 21h

ret;         
define_print_num
define_print_num_uns 
sprtMessage db " ", 0dh, 0ah, '$'
end begin
```

Этот код должен был выводить значения регистра `AX` три раза, каждый раз используя `print_num` которое считывает данные из нее. Первый раз использования `print_num` выводит конъюнкцию `AX BX`, должен вывести еще два раза значение из регистра `AX` измененное с помощью `OR` и `XOR`, но этого не происходит, **почему?** я понять не могу

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `int 21h` после вызова процедуры не нужен. Также возможно, что процедура изменяет значения регистров ax и bx.

Comment: @insolor это сделано чтобы выводимые числа не 'слипались' друг с другом, т. е. просто перенос строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим кусок кода:

```
mov ah, 9  ; <--
mov dx, offset sprtMessage
mov ax, 1111b  ; <--
mov bx, 1101b 
and ax, bx
```

Обратите внимание, что регистр `ah` - это старший байт регистра `ax`. Команда `mov ax, 1111b` перезаписывает регистр `ax`, целиком, по сути обнуляя старший байт.

В итоге, если `call print_num` никак не модифицирует регистр `ax` (а может и модифицировать, я этого не знаю), то `int 21h` вызывает не функцию `09h` (вывод строки) прерывания `21h`, а функцию `00h` - а это просто выход из программы.